# Does the Death Note corrupt the mind of a human user?

Tags: death-note

I noticed that when Light Yagami got the Death Note he became evil, so it made me wonder if the Death Note has the ability to corrupt a human user.

Comment: All situations where a person has power gives a chance to corrupts their minds, afect their morals.

Comment: I noticed someone who bought a hotdog crossed the street slower. Thus hotdogs causes slowness.

Comment: @Tyhja Objects in motion are relatively travelling through time at a slower pace than objects not in motion, the effect of him standing still to purchase the hot dog compared to the effect of him walking from your (the observers) point of view is your witnessing of the effects of time dilation due to relativity, not directly the hot dogs fault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Power corrupts; absolute power corrupts absolutely."

It appears that the Death Note does not change the owner's will to corrupt him directly.  Light, though, is corrupted by his rather insane ploy for power and world domination.  While he almost immediately exhibits megalomania, he seems to try to morally justify his actions.  By the end, he views himself as a God and cannot fathom his failure or that his actions are somehow wrong. Misa Misa, however, seems detached from those under her feet and doesn't seem to give much mind to whether her actions are moral at all. It seems that the Shinigami's expect this kind of behavior from human's given this power but they are too surprised by it to be directly bringing it about.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a person becomes corrupt if he gets the power to kill a person. So, not only a death note, but the power to kill people is itself, evil.

Comment: The Death Note has an important difference from more mundane ways of killing someone: it's anonymous. It's like the 4chan of murder. This allows even people like Misa and Mikami, who aren't super geniuses, to escape capture for a long time.

Comment: I have the power to kill people - like everyone who can hold a knife. Does that make me corrupt? Using this power is what indicates ones corruptnes and what makes one even more corrupt. The Death Note makes killing very easy, it lowers the inhibition threshold and it thus makes it easier to corrupt oneself further.

Answer (score 0):

The death note itself does not affect the users mind at all.

It is compareable to a gun just stronger/more effective.